# Need Powershell function to base64 encode files exactly like in bash

Tags: bash, powershell, base64, azure-resource-manager

In Azure, when deploying a vm I want to give it a startup script. This needs to be a base64 encoded string in the deployment template.

When I generate this string in WSL of my windows machine using `cat script.sh | base64 -w0` everything works fine. However, I'm in for automation using powershell and want to generate this that way.

When deploying, I'm getting errors that commands cannot be executed. I'm blaming that it cannot be decoded properly on the Azure side.

I'm using the following function to generate the base64 string in ps1

```
function base64 {
    param([string]$file)
    $text = get-content $file
    $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($text)
    return [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
}
```

When i decode that result in WSL using `echo "result-from-ps1" | base64 -d` it shows without line breaks, which might be the problem.

Comment: If `$file` is encoded in UTF8 you should use `$text = Get-Content $file -Encoding UTF8`

Comment: Thank you, but the result is the same. I guess if omitting the encoding, UTF8 is already the assumed default.

Comment: Try with additional `-raw` parameter [Ref](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/edf27b8d-00ce-42d3-b94e-2c822273f32a/encoding-decoding-file-causes-loss-of-line-endings?forum=winserverpowershell) `$text = Get-Content $file -Encoding UTF8 -Raw`

Comment: Still no luck, now the string is even longer, beforehand they were different but of identical length

Comment: You could try to strip the windows line ending `CR/LF` with `$test.Replace('\r\n','\n')`

Comment: I need correct myself. Adding -Raw to the command did indeed fix it, I screwed-up in comparing the values. Thank you!